# C++ : Reading file and store data in multi-vector

Tags: c++, file, vector

I am trying to read data file with the this format

```
T1: I1,I2,I5 
T2: I2,I4 
T3: I2,I3 
T4: I1,I2,I4 
T5: I1,I3 
T6: I2,I3 
T7: I1,I3 
T8: I1,I2,I3,I5 
T9: I1,I2,I3
```

I don't want to read the first column T1,T2,T3 ...... , but each line will be a dataset I want to start read after (space '  ' ) and end with each line and how can I separate the data according to (comma ',')

I wrote this code but it didn't work correctly and it reads the first column anyway

```
string CItem;

// set of elements
set< CItem > CItemSet;

//Transactions
 CItemSet CTransaction;

// set of transactions
vector< CTransaction > CTransactionSet;

ifstream inFile(inFileName);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Failed to open input file filename:." << inFileName;
    }

CTransactionSet transSet;
    CTransaction tran;
    string txtLine;
    // read every line from the stream
    while (getline(inFile, txtLine))
    {

        istringstream txtStream(txtLine);
        string txtElement;
        // read every element from the line that is seperated by commas
        // and put it into the vector or strings

        while (getline(txtStream, txtElement, ','))
        {
            if (txtElement == ": ") break;
            else tran.insert(txtElement);
        }
        transSet.push_back(tran);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by doing what you said R Sahu but the most important solution is by using .ignore so we don't read the part before the ' '

```
CTransactionSet transSet;
    string txtLine;
    // read every line from the stream
    while (getline(inFile, txtLine))
    {
        istringstream txtStream(txtLine);
        txtStream.ignore(txtLine.length(), ' ');
        // read every element from the line that is seperated by commas
        // and put it into the vector or strings
        string txtElement;
        CTransaction tran;
        while (getline(txtStream, txtElement, ','))
        {
            tran.insert(txtElement);
        }
        transSet.push_back(tran);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have

```
CTransaction tran;
```

outside the first `while` loop, items keep getting added to it. Move it inside the `while` loop.

```
CTransactionSet transSet;
string txtLine;
// read every line from the stream
while (getline(inFile, txtLine))
{
    CTransaction tran;
```